# Auto-filling a formula across a large number of cells

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm attempting to reorganise data across 25 tables and reorganise them into 32 variables.

To do this I need to select a specific cell from each table and add them into a variable table with an IFERROR Check. the spacing between tables is even so the required cell would be 36 cell places after the next cell.

For example Cell1 would be =IFERROR(A53,-1) but cell2 would be =IFERROR(A89,-1) and Cell3 would be =IFERROR(A125,-1).

I would think that Excel would be able to pick up on this pattern and autofill with a simple drag down but it is not working. When I also try to drag right it doesnt go A53,A54,A55... but instead A53,A54,A55,[drag fill begins],C53,D53,E53,F53.

I have tried every variation of drag and fill and expected fill I could think of but nothing is working. Is there a way to set cells to say "copy the celll above/beside you but add 36 on to the cell count"?

Comment: For your vertical range you can use `=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,17+36*ROW(A1)),-1)` and drag that down

Comment: I say this every time - screenshot/sample example saves us / me (aka 'us') eons RE: attempting to decipher/translate a poem into actionable requsts.